# Python : How to tokenize from file?

Tags: python, text, io, token, tokenize

I'm a newbie in python. I would like to know how to tokenize twitter data from file.

My code is :

```
with codecs.open('example.csv', 'r',"utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = f.readlines()
        tokens = word_tokenize(tweet["text"])
        print(tokens)
```

But error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-98b6d77c2fcf> in <module>()
      2     for line in f:
      3         tweet = f.readlines()
----> 4         tokens = word_tokenize(tweet["text"])
      5         print(tokens)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I improve my code ?

Comment: what is `word_tokenize` ? and also `tweet` is a `list` , for accessing list items you should reference them with indices ( as error says)

Comment: word_tokenize from code : from pythainlp.tokenize import word_tokenize and I would like to collect texts  from example.csv to tweet

Comment: The problem shown in the code has **absolutely nothing to do with** the question being asked.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**

OK, first things first... I used [this](https://github.com/sudar/pig-samples/blob/master/data/tweets.csv) (sample.csv with tweets) file in order to do my test. Then here is the simple code as per your example:

```
import codecs
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')

with codecs.open('example.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = f.readlines()

        tokenized_sents = [nltk.word_tokenize(i) for i in tweet]
        for i in tokenized_sents:
            print(i)
```

this is tested and working as per screenshot:

[image]

---

hmmmm.... you are passing the String with tweet["text"])  in the word_tokenize which accepts one argument as Integer.

it should be something like

```
with codecs.open('example.csv', 'r',"utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = f.readlines()

        tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(i) for i in tweet]
        for i in tokenized_sents:
            print i
```

Comment: Thank you Oetoni , it showed : File "<ipython-input-16-93b8a0f7886d>", line 7
    print i
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: here...full working code with screen shot :) and file that I used

Comment: Thank you so much Oetoni. It works !!!!!!  and sorry I don't know to put () on print i hahahahahaaaaaaaa.

Answer (score -1):

If you iterate over lines you don't have to call readlines:

```
with codecs.open('example.csv', 'r',"utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        # line is each line
```

If you want to read a csv with columns "tweet" use this:

```
import csv
from nltk import word_tokenize 
with open('example.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
   for row in reader:
       tweet = row["tweet"]
       print("Tweet: %s" % tweet)
       tokens = word_tokenize(tweet)
       print(tokens)
```

See Python 3 documentation on [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) and [open](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Thank you coffeemakr , my column in csv file names "text" so I change from your code  row["text"] and I got an error like this

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f9aed31a5a4b> in <module>()
      2     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
      3     for row in reader:
----> 4         tweet = row["text"]
      5         print("Tweet: %s" % tweet)
      6         tokens = word_tokenize(tweet)

KeyError: 'text'

Comment: This means that the DictReader doesn't find a field "text". Printing `row` may help you debug your problem. Also check if the CSV really has a column "text".